# How can I send the parent id to the hasMany JSON query with Ember.js?

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I'd like to include the Server id field in the JSON query for Networks.  The App.NetworkRoute doesn't get called and I'm not sure why.  I see the query for /networks/ids[]=1.... I can work with that but I need to get the Server's id because I have overlapping Network id's depending on which server is selected.

It's a proprietary system I pull the data from and it wouldn't be easy to change without having to do double data entry.

Here's the Ember.js section of the code:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.route('server',{path: "/"});
  this.resource('server');
  this.resource('networks');
  });

});

App.ServerRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.find('server');
  }  
});

App.NetworkRoute = Ember.Route.extend({  
  model: function (server) {  
    return this.store.find('network', {serverId: server.id});
  }
});

var attr = DS.attr,
    hasMany = DS.hasMany,
    belongsTo = DS.belongsTo;

App.Server = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  ip: DS.attr('string'),
  networks: DS.hasMany('network',{async:true})
});

App.Network = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  server: belongsTo('server')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

they aren't related routes, they are like 3 different folders all sitting at root.

And Network should be Networks

Do you want them like this, networks are children of servers?

```
this.resource('server', function(){
  this.resource('networks');
})
```

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources